# MATLAB App Designer UIAxes Plot is completely blank

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, matlab-app-designer

If I simply start a new App Designer project and drag the option "Axes (2D)" to the main canvas, I get the component app.UIAxes, but it is completely blank. While I'm dragging it, I can see the default labels, title, ticks, and so on, but whenever I drop it it just becomes blank. I also can't seem to make it work via code either, as shown below ([link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibhBS.png)). Any ideas on why this is happening and a possible workaround?

```
function EditFieldValueChanged(app, event)
        value = app.EditField.Value;
        x=linspace(0,10);
        y=value*x;
        plot(app.UIAxes,x,y)
    end
```

Comment: It should work, you may contact MathWorks support because the axis should be visible and your code should work too.

Comment: Try switching to so `software  opengl` [Control OpenGL rendering](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/opengl.html), in case there it's a rendering issue.